# Why is some styles/headings are excluded from bookmark when converting from word to pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, bookmarks

I created custom styles/headings for my document
One is called "Title Custom" and another is called "Subtitle Custom"

But when I convert into pdf with the bookmark setting selected, the only thing that show on the pdf bookmarks is the part that is in "Title Custom" style.

How can I automatically include the "Subtitle Custom" style part in my pdf bookmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Paragraph properties of your style ensure that Outline level is set to Level 1 or above.